# iOS - Testing view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I've got a really weird and unexplainable problem and it's like the whole day I'm trying to fix it without any result.

I have setup a testing target for my iOS project, following the doc steps.
I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a).
I'm also using kiwi. Every test works fine, apart when it comes to load the view of a view controller with xib.

The view controller is a simple UIViewController with a MKMapView, a button and a searchbar, all properly hooked to the owner's IBOutlets.

In the test I'm writing something like:

```
__block MapViewController *mapVC = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController"
                                              bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.myorg.MyAppTest"]];
it(@"Loads the view", ^{
   [mapVC loadView];
});
```

While executing the test (on iPhone Simulator 5.0) I get a bunch of these in the console:

> ERROR: System image table has not been initialized. Do not ask for
>   images or set up UI before UIApplicationMain() has been called.

After that I almost always get this error

> [__NSCFType pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x19cb970

On iPhone 6 Simulator I get initially this error

> Unknown Device Type. Using UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone based on screen
>   size

Followed by this

> -[__NSCFType screenFontWithRenderingMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeba1540

I hope someone can help me, this thing is driving me mad.